# Spring Cloud Gateway And Spring Security Passing Authenticated Roles to Microservices

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud-gateway

Let's assume that;

We have Spring Boot(2) services ;
Microservice A,
Microservice B,
Microservice C,

And we want to aggregate them with Spring Cloud Gateway and do token authentication if needed http paths to specific services.

Now assume we authenticated in api-gateway and then take roles etc. But I don't want to one by one permit specific http paths like `/service-b/public-area` with ServerHttpSecurity chaining.

Instead of this I want to use in `microservice B` with `@PreAuthorize("hasRole(ROLE_USER)")` annotation on my mapping methods.
So I can handle partial independence authorization in microservices. Because I need to work just on specific microservice when have any task.

But I couldn't any documentation about passing spring security roles in [Spring Cloud Gateway docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/single/spring-cloud-gateway.html).

Can anybody have any answer or experience and advices about this problem ?

Comment: I think that you should do a proxy pass in Gateway and on each microservice authenticate on authentication service, In order to authenticate you can verify which users are authorized.

Comment: @JonathanJohx That's not what I mean, I don't want to implement authentication in each microservice, instead of that I want to pass SecurityContext to microservices.

Comment: then you need to create a security logic on gateway service before you pass to your microservices. you can take a look this link https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-securing-services , let me know if this helps you to your question.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this please?